# Anaconda not recognizing Elastic Search Module in centOS

Tags: python, elasticsearch, centos, anaconda

I am running centOS 7, and I recently installed the Anaconda python interpreter. This is now the default on the machine. I need to use the API to connect to an Elastic Search instance to pull data to run stats functions on. I ran the command `pip install elasticsearch`, and it completed sucessfully. But when I run this line of code

`from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch`

I get this error

`ImportError: no module named elasticsearch`

I checked the packages in the `~/anaconda2/pkgs` directory, and there is no elasticsearch package there. How can I remedy this problem?

Comment: What is the output of `which pip`?

Comment: @darthbith `~/anaconda2/bin/pip`

Comment: I can't reproduce this, so I recommend you `pip uninstall elasticsearch urllib3` and `conda install -c conda-forge elasticsearch`. Only Conda installed packages are put into the `pkgs` directory. If you pip-install packages, they go in the `site-packages` directory (which I think is under `libs`)

Comment: @darthbith Hi I'm having the same issue, I installed elasticsearch with "conda install -c conda-forge elasticsearch" because your command generated "install: cannot stat 'conda-forge': No such file or directory". It installed fine without errors, but still in my jupyter notebook it says "ImportError: no module named elasticsearch". Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you install Jupyter Notebook into the same environment as `elasticsearch`?